# Overflow not hidden while css animation in safari

Tags: html, css

First the bars are in front of the dog.
Then the bars go up with a translate css animation by hover.
Last the bars stay up on hover.

But the bars are not overflow : hidden while its transition is animating.
In google chrome it works fine but in SAFARI it shows the bars until the animation is done.

edit: while you're on the website, can someone explain why (if you resize the window) the background "dissapears" in the "PROGRAMMA"-page but the boxing arena stays, you can scroll to the right when you resize.

Here is the [link](http://student.howest.be/robbe.verhoest/20172018/major2/) to the website. The div is in the bottom of the homepage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to the `.hondvdweek` parent container.

```
.hondvdweek {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```